# Open issues with split reference counting example in the "c++ concurrency in action" book

Tags: c++, multithreading, concurrency, memory-leaks

I have two questions about listing 7.11 in section 7.2.4 of the "c++ concurrency in action" book (second edition). Following is a code snippet (from listing 7.11) for a lock-free stack implementation with explicit split reference counting mechanism to avoid memory leaks (I included only relevant code to my questions).

```
template<typename T>
class lock_free_stack
{
private:
    struct node;
    struct counted_node_ptr
    {
        int external_count;
        node* ptr;
    };
    struct node
    {
        std::shared_ptr<T> data;
        std::atomic<int> internal_count;
        counted_node_ptr next;
        node(T const& data_):
            data(std::make_shared<T>(data_)),
            internal_count(0)
        {}
    };
    std::atomic<counted_node_ptr> head;
public:
    ~lock_free_stack()
    {
        while(pop());
    }
    void push(T const& data)
    {
        counted_node_ptr new_node;
        new_node.ptr=new node(data);
        new_node.external_count=1;
        new_node.ptr->next=head.load();
        while(!head.compare_exchange_weak(new_node.ptr->next,new_node));
    }
};
```

The reference counting mechanism is based on two counters: *external_count and internal*_*count. The external*_*count* is part of a wrapper (of type *counted_node_ptr*) to the stack nodes (of type *node*). The *internal_count* is kept inside the *node* structures.

**Q1:** In the *push* method, a new *counted_node_ptr* struct is created for a new item and finally it is pointed at by the  *head* pointer (assume for simplicity that only one thread is doing push at a time). However, the *counted_node_ptr* struct is allocated on the stack so when *push()* is returned, *head* should be assumed to be a dangling pointer.
Am I missing something here ?

**Q2:**
The text says: "*One possible technique involves the use of not one but two reference counts for each node: an internal count and an external count. The sum of these values is the total number of references to the node. The external count is kept alongside the pointer to the node and is increased every time the pointer is read. When the reader is finished with the node, it decreases the internal count. A simple operation that reads the pointer will leave the external count increased by one and the internal count decreased by one when it’s finished. When the external count/pointer pairing is no longer required (the node is no longer accessible from a location accessible to multiple threads), the internal count is increased by the value of the external count minus one and the external counter is discarded. Once the internal count is equal to zero, there are no outstanding references to the node and it can be safely deleted.*".

I don't fully understand this scheme of reference counting using two counters: Why one counter is not sufficient? what each counter actually represents ? Does anyone have a reference (link) to a formal description of this scheme?

Comment: Before C++20 [`std::atomic`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) didn't initialized the contained object. The `head` member variable is unuseable until you have properly initialized it. You should probably make sure that `node::next` is properly initialized as well. Adding explicit initializations is a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

If your head is simply `node pointer` then on load you need atomically load `head`  and then atomically increment `internal_count`. In between of `head.load()` and `internal_count.fetch_add(1)` something can happen so you need to lock and receive `shared_ptr` which is not `lockfree`. In simple load on `node pointer`:

```
 node* old_head=head.load();
```

You already use pointer but since `internal_count` not incremented yet nothing prevents from another thread to delete it.

In your example you use wrapper for `node pointer` not `pointer` itself so you need some `external_count` to safely access it. You increment `external_count` in copy of `old_counter`(`new_counter`) and if `old_counter` still `head` you replace `head` with incremented (owned)  copy of `old_counter` in **one** `atomic` CAS :

```
void increase_head_count(counted_node_ptr& old_counter)
 {
   counted_node_ptr new_counter;
   do
   {
     new_counter=old_counter;
     ++new_counter.external_count;
   }
   while(!head.compare_exchange_strong(old_counter,new_counter)); 
   old_counter.external_count=new_counter.external_count;
 }
```

So after `increase_head_count` you can safely access `ptr`.

Atomic `internal_count`  you need to prevent race in `std::shared_ptr<T> pop()` between thread in `if(head.compare_exchange_strong(old_head,ptr->next))` and thread in `else if(ptr->internal_count.fetch_sub(1)==1)`